# Substitute NA values with another column's values

Tags: r

I have 2 columns with survey answers:

```
subject_id | income | income unknown |
1          | 1000   | NA             |
2          | 15000  | NA             |
3          | NA     | 15000          |
4          | NA     | 10000          |
5          | 15000  | NA             |
```

I would like to merge the two columns. The second column has a value if the 1st income column was not answered (in most cases at least).

I thought of substituting `NA`s with zeros and then summing the two columns up, but that doesn't really work.

Comment: So, how many columns you want in expected?

Comment: You want `coalesce` from `dplyr`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `coalesce`

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>%
    transmute(subject_id, income = coalesce(income, income_unknown))
#   subject_id income
#1          1   1000
#2          2  15000
#3          3  15000
#4          4  10000
#5          5  15000
```

---

Other `base R` options include `rowSums`, `pmax`, `pmin` etc if there is only one non-NA element per row

```
df1$income <- rowSums(df1[-1], na.rm = TRUE)
df1$income <- do.call(pmax, c(df1[-1], na.rm = TRUE))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(subject_id = 1:5, income = c(1000L, 15000L, NA, 
NA, 15000L), income_unknown = c(NA, NA, 15000L, 10000L, NA)),
.Names = c("subject_id", 
"income", "income_unknown"), class = "data.frame",
 row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: the new income column becomes NULL when i use coalesce

Comment: @PCUnique  It is not happening on my side with `dplyr_0.5.0`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ifelse()`

```
df$income.new <- ifelse(is.na(df$income), df$income_unknown, df$income)
```